# How check params in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I should send params from form to controller and then send them to model. I need check them in model. Please help...
Form:

```
<form action="questions">
<input type="text" name="user_name_param" /><br>
<input type="text" name="user_email_param" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="send" />
</form>
```

Question Controller:

```
user_id = User.new.check_user(params[:user_name_param], params[:user_email_param])
```

User Model:

```
validates :name_param,  :presence => true, 
                :length => {:minimum => 1, :maximum => 254}

validates :email_param, :presence => true, 
                :length => {:minimum => 3, :maximum => 254},
                :uniqueness => true,
                :format => {:with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i}

 def check_user(name_param, email_param)
 if (name_param && email_param).valid?
 User.where(:user_name => name_param, :user_email => email_param).first.try(:id) || false
 else render :template => "questions/auth_form"
 end
```

end

I have **undefined method `valid?' for nil:NilClass** error.

Answer (score 0):

- First, that form is really unconventional. Read about [form_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag), [form_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) and FormHelpers.
- Secondly, `if (name_param && email_param).valid?` is wrong. `name_param && email_param` performs boolean operation, if both are truthy, it gives back the second result; else `NilClass` in this case. `valid?` is not defined on these classes, it is defined for ActiveRecord objects.
- Third, `render :template => "questions/auth_form"` is wrong again. `render` is ActionController method. You can't use it like this in your model; this type of logic should be present in your controller.

**General solution**:
You are probably trying to find the user who matches with that email and name; else render authorization page. Perhaps this controller logic will suffice:

```
@user = User.where(["user_name = ? and user_email = ?", params[user_name_param], params[user_email_param]])
if @user.valid? 
  #DO this
else
  #render that
end
```

`#find_by` for Rails 4.